What limits the size of a nuclear power generator?
Nuclear microreactors like Westinghouse's eVinci are small enough to fit on a flatbed semi-truck, and NuScale Power's small modular reactor (SMR) is small, too; but are there smaller nuclear power generators? What limits the size of a nuclear power generator?

I think this would be better asked to engineering stack exchange since they would have better ability to get you the practical limits of a nuclear reactor.

@Triatticus Thanks for the suggestion. I've asked it there.

While you're at it, be careful in your terminology.  You seem to be thinking nuclear fission reactors, where a nuclear fission is instigated by neutron bombardment of fissile nuclei, with the neutrons coming from the fission.  There are things called nuclear power generators that are directly powered by natural radioactive decay which isn't part of a reaction -- various deep-space probes, and Soviet (because -- Soviet) earth-based remote weather stations used this technique, as well as some abortive attempts at other applications in the West in the 1950's.

To be a critical reactor, the material and geometry have to be in a balance where the number of neutrons created by fission match the number of neutrons being absorbed and leaking from the system. The absorptions and fissions are determined by the material, and the leakage is determined by the geometric configuration.
For example, the "Godiva" reactor is a small critical mass of U-235.  U-235 is a very good fuel, but not the best, and geometry with the least amount of leakage is a sphere.
However, I suspect you are asking about the smallest power reactor, where you can extract usable energy.  In this case, the size of the reactor will be determined by the amount of power you want to extract, and how you can remove the power and stay within the material limitations.  The eVinci reactor produces a fairly small amount of electricity and can fit on a truck.  The NuScale SMR produces more power and is larger.  A large PWR produces much more power, but is also much larger.
